# When i try to update the record it is getting duplicated and call the function which add new record

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is my controller for updating new credit card , I put a hidden input to give me the id and I will find it by id

```
@RequestMapping("/updateCreditCard") 
public String UpdateCreditCard(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model,Principal principal) {
      users user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
      UserPayment userPayment = userPaymentService.findById(id).get();
      UserBilling userBilling = userPayment.getUserBilling();
      if (userPayment.getId() == userBilling.getUserPayment().getId()) {
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("userPayment", userPayment);
        model.addAttribute("userBilling", userBilling);
        model.addAttribute("userPaymentList", user.getUserPaymentList());
        List <String> stateList = EGConstant.ListOfStatesNames;
        Collections.sort(stateList);
        model.addAttribute("stateList", stateList);
        model.addAttribute("addNewCreditsCards",  true);
        model.addAttribute("classActiveBilling", true);
     } else {
        return "redirect:/error";
       }
    return "myProfile";
   }
```

This is the method for addNewCreditcards to the database when I try to update the credit card, it calls again not update but it makes me a new record

```
 RequestMapping(value = "/addNewCreditsCards", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
 public String addNewCredidCard(@ModelAttribute("userPayment") UserPayment userPayment,
                                @ModelAttribute("userBilling") UserBilling userBilling,
                                Model model,Principal principal) 
 {
    users user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
    userService.saveUserBillingAndPayment(userBilling, userPayment, user);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("userPaymentList", user.getUserPaymentList());
    model.addAttribute("classActiveBilling", true);
    model.addAttribute("listOfCreditsCards", true);
    return "myProfile";
 }
```

**And this is my template  it divided to tabs and I use class to append to appear the selected tab**

```
Billing  tab 
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-4"
   th:classappend="${classActiveBilling}? 'in active'">
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default" style="border: none;">
<div class="panel-body"
   style="background-color: #ededed; margin- 
   top: 20px;">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
   <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a
      th:href="@{/listOfCreditsCards}"
      th:style="${listOfCreditsCards}? 'color:red'">List Of
      Credit Card</a>
   </li>
   <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a
      th:href="@{/addNewCreditsCards}"
      th:style="${addNewCreditsCards}? 'color:red'">Add new
      Credit Card</a>
   </li>
</ol>
<div th:if="${listOfCreditsCards}">
   <form th:action="@{/setDefaultPayment}" method="post">
      <table class="table">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <td>Default</td>
               <td>Credit Card</td>
               <td>Operations</td>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr th:each="userPayment : ${userPaymentList}">
               <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${userPayment.id}" />
               <td><input type="radio" name="defaultUserPaymentId"
                  th:value="${userPayment.id}"
                  th:checked="${userPayment.defaultPayment}" /></td>
               <td th:text="${#strings.toUpperCase(userPayment.type)}"></td>
               <td><a style="text-decoration:none"
                  th:href="@{/updateCreditCard?id=}+${userPayment.id}">
                  <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Update&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                  </a> <a style="text-decoration:none" th:href="@{/removeCreditCard?id=}+${userPayment.id}">
                  <i class="fas fa-times"></i> Delete
                  </a>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <button class="btn btn-prmary" type="submit">Save</button>
   </form>
</div>
<div th:if="${addNewCreditsCards}" >
   <form th:action="@{/addNewCreditsCards}" method="POST">
      <div class="bg-info" th:if="${updateUserPaymentInfo}">
         User info updated
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${userPayment.id}" />  
      <div class="form-group">
         <h5>* Give a name to your card</h5>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" th:name="cardName" placeholder="Enter credit card name"
            th:value="${userPayment.cardName}" required="required" />
      </div>
      <!--  Biiling Addresse -->
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="billingName">* Name</label> <input type="text"
            id="billingName" class="form-control" 
            th:name="userBillingName" placeholder="Reciver Name" required="required"
            th:value="${userBilling.userBillingName}" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="billingAddresse">* Street Name</label> <input
            type="text" id="userBillingStreet1" class="form-control"
            th:name="userBillingStreet1" placeholder="Street Name 1" required="required"
            th:value="${userBilling.userBillingStreet1}" /> 
         <br />
         <input type="text" id="userBillingStreet2" class="form-control"
            th:name="userBillingStreet2" placeholder="Street Number"
            th:value="${userBilling.userBillingStreet1}"  />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="userBillingCity">* City</label> <input type="text "
                  id="userBillingCity" class="form-control"
                  th:name="userBillingCity" placeholder="Enter your city" required="required"
                  th:value="${userBilling.userBillingCity}" />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label for="userBillingState">* State</label> 
            <select th:name="userBillingState" class="form-control" 
               th:value="${userBilling.userBillingState}"  required="required">
               <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" >select a state</option>
               <option th:each="state : ${stateList}" th:text="${state}" 
                  th:selected="(${userBilling.userBillingState} == ${state})"
                  ></option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="ZipCode">* zipCode</label> <input type="number "
                  id="userBillingZipCode" class="form-control"
                  th:name="userBillingZipCode" placeholder="Enter your zip code" required="required"
                  th:value="${userBilling.userBillingZipCode}" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--  CreditCard Information -->
      <hr>
      <div class="form-group">
         <h5>Credit card information</h5>
      </div>
      <div  class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/image/creditcard.png" /><br/>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="cardType">* Select Card Type</label>
               <select class="form-control" th:value="${userPayment.type}" id="type" th:name="type">
                  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" >Choose your credit card type</option>
                  <option value="visa" >Visa</option>
                  <option value="masterCard" >Master Card</option>
                  <option value="discover" th:value="${userPayment.type}">Discover</option>
                  <option value="CIB" >CIB</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="holderName" > * Holder Name</label>
               <input class="form-control" type="text" th:name="holderName" id="holderName" th:value="${userPayment.holderName}"
                  required="required " placeholder="Enter Card Holder Name" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="cardNumber" > * Card Number</label>
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input class="form-control" type="tel" th:name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber" th:value="${userPayment.cardNumber}"
                     required="required " placeholder="Enter Card Number " autocomplete="off" />
                  <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-7">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="Expiration Date" style="margin-left:175px"> * Expiration Date</label>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                     <select class="form-control" required="required" name="expiryMonth" id="expiryMonth" th:value="${userPayment.expiryMonth}">
                        <option disabled >-- Month --</option>
                        <option value="01" >Jan (01)</option>
                        <option value="02" >Feb (02)</option>
                        <option value="03" >Mars (03)</option>
                        <option value="04" >April (04)</option>
                        <option value="05" >May (05)</option>
                        <option value="06" >June (06)</option>
                        <option value="07" >July (07)</option>
                        <option value="08" >Aug (08)</option>
                        <option value="09" >Sept (09)</option>
                        <option value="10" >Oct (10)</option>
                        <option value="11" >Nov (11)</option>
                        <option value="12" >Dec (12)</option>
                     </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                     <select class="form-control" required="required" name="expiryYear" id="expiryYear" th:value="${userPayment.expiryYear}">
                        <option disabled="disabled">-- Year --</option>
                        <option value="2019">2019</option>
                        <option value="2019">2020</option>
                        <option value="2019">2021</option>
                        <option value="2019">2022</option>
                        <option value="2019">2023</option>
                        <option value="2019">2024</option>
                        <option value="2019">2025</option>
                        <option value="2019">2026</option>
                     </select>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="cvc">*Cvs Code</label>
               <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="cvc" name="cvc" th:value="${userPayment.cvc}" 
                  placeholder="Enter Cvc Code" required="required"/>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save All</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: kindly format your code. It is difficult to read. Also, put the REST url you are using for updation and creation.

Comment: They are above the controller  for updatig and creation

Comment: Did you try putting some logging in both the controller method? I copied the syntax of your methods and it's working fine for me. `localhost:8080/updateCreditCard ` is calling the update controller only. Kindly upload the update request you are using.

Comment: put `sysout` first line in both the controller. Or use debugger to see whether the request is going to the wrong controller, or something else is causing the issue.

Comment: yaa it call the update controller but when i click on update it make me a new record but the previous record updates

Comment: then there is not any problem with the controllers and the mappings. Double check the logic you have written in the controller method of update. Put breakpoints and debug to check where the execution is going.

Comment: everything is right but the problem it think it is a new record and add it but it update it also

Comment: you mean to say -> Update controller first create a record and then update that record. Please be clear to what you are trying to explain.

Comment: this is what i am tring to say . the update controller create a new one and update the second with the same information